# Utility of contextSource in spring ldap

Tags: spring, spring-ldap

What is the Utility of contextSource in spring ldap?

Answer (score 0):

- ContextSource is an interface to be implemented to create and configure a `DirContext` instance which a service for updating , searching and retrieving objec from LDAP directory
- `LdapContextSource` is an implementation of `ContextSource` which return `DirContext` based on ldap config params (ip, port, baseDn, ...)